# Angularjs Paging not working

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am developing website in angularjs with WebAPI. I am showing car details(with image,model name and price). I have three dropdowns. Based on the dropdown selected values i am binding values to div as below.

```
 <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid" ng-repeat="car in carDetails.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage),((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
                <img class="car" src="{{car.WebImageURL}}">
                <div class="car-name">{{car.make}}<span class="make">{{car.model}}</span></div>
                <div class="car-des">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
                <div class="car-price">{{car.Price}} <span class="sar">{{car.style}}</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Below is my controller code.

```
function getcadetails(baseurl)
       {  
           debugger;
           var arrallcarDetails = new Array();
                $http.get(baseurl).success(function (data) {
                    $.map(data.data, function (item) {
                     arrallcarDetails.push(item);
                     });
                    $scope.carDetails = arrallcarDetails;
                   // paging $scope.viewby = 10;
                    $scope.totalItems = $scope.carDetails.length;
                    $scope.currentPage = 4;
                    $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
                    $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show
                    $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
                        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
                    };
                    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
                        console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
                    };
                    $scope.setItemsPerPage = function (num) {
                        $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
                        $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first paghe
                    }
             }).error(function (status) {
             });
        }
```

Below is sample data(Only 1 row)

```
{"ID":0,"VendorID":0,"make":"HONDA","model":"2012","style":"SEDAN","ODO":null,"VIN":null,"ModelYear":0,"Price":45,"InteriorColor":null,"ExteriorColor":null,"WebImageURL":"http://localhost:49518/App/WebImageURL/yaris.png","TabImageURL":null,"MobileImageURL":null,"IsActive":null,"IsLocked":null,"DateCreated":null,"DateModified":null,"makeID":0,"modelID":0,"styleID":0},
```

My problem is arrallcarDetails will hold all data but in html page nothing is displaying. May I know is anything i am doing wrong? I am trying hard to figure out the mistek. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you forgot `$scope.$apply` in your `.success( .. )` function

Comment: Thanks. I removed slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage),((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) from ng-repeat and working without pagination. so is anything i am missing there?

Comment: Hi Legust where i should apply $scope.$apply?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put it here

```
  function getcadetails(baseurl)
   {  
       debugger;
       var arrallcarDetails = new Array();
            $http.get(baseurl).success(function (data) {
                $.map(data.data, function (item) {
                 arrallcarDetails.push(item);
                 });
                $scope.carDetails = arrallcarDetails;
               // paging $scope.viewby = 10;
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.carDetails.length;
                $scope.currentPage = 4;
                $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
                $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show
                $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
                    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
                };
                $scope.pageChanged = function () {
                    console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
                };
                $scope.setItemsPerPage = function (num) {
                    $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
                    $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first paghe
                }
                $scope.$apply(); // ------- here!
         }).error(function (status) {
         });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I put that but ended up with [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress error

Comment: That is weird, can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr example?

Comment: Thanks. https://plnkr.co/edit/PbUvQwL7t87zGatT3VK0?p=preview i have updated my plunker here. Instead of calling data from server i hardcoded.

Comment: Ok, your plunkr is not working, I can understand problem with $http or other dependencies, but I cant find even your *hardoceded data from server*. So can you fix plunkr example please

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. i edited plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/PbUvQwL7t87zGatT3VK0?p=preview In  $scope.carDetails  i have hardcoded data.